# Single Cycle Datapath MIPS - Adding swap instruction

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, mips

Let's say I want to make a new MIPS instruction called: swap $rs $rt , which exchanges the contents of the registers $rs and $rt.  Using an auxiliary variable aux, this new instruction is specified as follows in the RTL language:

```
aux←Reg[Rs];

Reg[Rs]←Reg[Rt];

Reg[Rt]←aux;

PC←PC + 4;
```

How can I modify the functional blocks to allow this instruction to execute in a single cycle? I am thinking I should just add another RegFile/ALU. I cannot access any additional registers. Additionally I need to know whether there would be additional control signals required, and what they would be for.

---

This is what the current architecture looks like.

[image: block diagram]

Functional blocks include the RegFile, Data Memory (for instructions like load/store), etc. As for my efforts in solving this, I've considered all functional blocks and I am unsure as to what blocks would provide the auxiliary variable.

Comment: Confusing question right? I'm doing the assignment too. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-two-numbers-without-using-temporary-variable/ Method 2 is the idea.

Comment: Yeah, I just am not sure what block would perform that operation or what series of blocks would.

Comment: @helpyhippo No, that's not relevant. This question is asking about hardware design, not C programming. (Also, for what it's worth: that trick is completely useless.)

Comment: @duskwulff : This trick doesn't address the question (single cycle swap), but it is not useless. It can be coded in hardware for a multicycle swap instruction. Avoiding a temporary register and re-using structures already present in the ALU (adder, subtract,  xor) can make sense (SWAP is not used a lot, it should not compromise the performance of the rest of the CPU). Alternatively, in a pipelined CPU, the temporary register can be simply data deeper in the pipeline, as a way go back in time.

Comment: @TEMLIB would a single ALU be sufficient to execute https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm or would there have to be multiple ALUs? It would be 3 XORs have the algorithm occur.

Comment: @AppreciateIt : For a multicycle implementation, you re-use the single ALU and make a more complex instruction decoder (most "real" CPUs have a few multicycle instructions anyway, even RISCs). For single cycle, you need to change the CPU to allow two register writes at once, and add a direct path from a register read port to the second register write port for that special instruction, in addition to the path crossing the ALU (configured to do a register MOVE/copy operation),

Answer (score 1):

In generic RTL, both transfers can occur in parallel:

```
Reg[Rs] <= Reg[Rt];
Reg[Rt] <= Reg[Rs];
PC <= PC + 4;
```

However, the usual block diagram for the [MIPS architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#Microarchitectures_based_on_the_MIPS_instruction_set) (shown below) only has a single write path to the register file, which means that it is simply not possible to a register swap in a single cycle.

[image: MIPS block diagram]

Comment: The question is what functional block(s) could do this.

Comment: It must be possible, otherwise the question would state otherwise as an option...Thanks anyway.